# Are code examples indexed by search engines?

Tags: seo, google-search

If I have a code example in a blog article with escaped content wrapped inside of a `<pre><code>` tag combination then will a search engine read that? What about if the code is also syntax highlighted (so it's littered with `<span>` tags with special, color-based classes)?

Comment: It will read it, but there's really no way to know if the search engine would use it for it's searching other than through testing it yourself or asking the devs directly.

Comment: You ask about "search engines" and your tag says [tag:google-search]. So, do you want to know this for Google Search?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is in the page source, crawlers can see it. They might treat it and use it different ways. it is Google and so anything happen in their algorithms.